# Wp7 windows phone 7 media element not playing stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, element, media

i have been trying to play some sound(.wav) from a website link on windows phone 7 using the media element.

MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement(); 
 mediaElement.source = new uri("http://api.microsofttranslator.com%2fwav"); 
 mediaElement.play();

doesnt do anything.

i tried implementing handlers or even try to use the Webclient class to download the stream and play it but it has the same problem i dont hear anything.

and also i copied the uri to the browser and it played the wave i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Microsoft Translator`, you can add a `Service Reference` to the API SOAP service. The Service Client exposes the [SpeakAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512436.aspx) method which will return the URL of the `WAV` file. You can then use your `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` to download the stream and play it. There's example code in this [blog post](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/ms-translator-api-text-to-speech-wp7/).

Comment: thanks, i think i should have from the start saved the wav to the isolated storage and then played it